# Exchange 2010 - Distribution Group not receive emails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

Exchange 2010 - Distribution Group not receiving emails.

Background: We have a distribution group (Team - DBAs) which contains 1 internal email address and 2 external email address.

The Problem: 
1) When sending an email to this distribution group no one receives the email. 
2) If you type in each email address individually into the To field the email is received. 
3) If you type the distribution group name, then click the + to break the group into individual addresses you receive a delivery failure to the external email addresses only.

This happens if we send the email through OWA or Outlook.

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing the external contacts from the group. Then adding them again.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking the group means the group isn't being used - it was used to get the entries in to the address line only.
Therefore I would suspect that you actually have two issues.

1. The group isn't working as expected.
2. The external recipients aren't working as expected via the contacts that you created.

Therefore start with the second issue. What does the NDR say? 
If you remove the two external recipients, does the group work then?